# Change the border colour in Fancybox v2.1.1

Tags: javascript, css, fancybox, border

I have searched everywhere and can not see that this has been answered for the version 2.1.1.

All I want to do is change the border colour of the fancybox from white to something else.

Please can any tell me which part of the CSS I need to change.

Comment: We really need to see what code you have already before we can answer you.

Comment: @Kevin Anthony Oppegaard Rose No, you don't need to see any code from the OP, because this question obviously refers to the default styles of [Fancybox](http://fancyapps.com/fancybox/). Nonetheless, the question shows, that the author doesn't had searched the provided default stylesheets for Fancybox…

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I guess you missed to search the Fancybox stylesheets nor did you looked at the styles via some browsers developer tools. The white "border" isn't a border but a white background of the underlying `DIV`:

```
.fancybox-skin {
    background: #F9F9F9;
}
```

Just look at the `jquery.fancybox.css` and modify the mentioned selectors styles.

Comment: or add it in your own css declarations to override the defaults (instead of messing with the original files ;)

Comment: Hi Feeela, thank you for such a quick answer.

I had already searched the forums and also used Google extensively.

I'd love to see a reference to that css value in a link other than this one!

I appreciate your help and whilst you don't put yourself across in a very happy manner I am greatful to you and also this forum for helping me.

Many thanks

Answer (score 0):

If you referring to the overlaying-image that opens after you click the link, then you can use

```
.fancybox-content {
    border-color: #[your color]; /* this gets you the required color. Tested*/
}
```

.fancy-box is the class used by the  that encloses the overlaid-image.